# Delegate a non-failable initializer to a failable initializer

Tags: swift, enums, initializer

**Edit**

A simple solutions was found thanks to @Airspeed Velocity, with a little twist added since this is parsed from JSON. Allow the initializer to take `AnyObject?` and default to `Unknown` (or `Invalid`):

```
init(value: AnyObject?) {
  if let value = value as? Int
    ,let result = Result(rawValue: value) {
      self = result
  } else {
    self = .Unknown
  }
}
```

//

**Original**

I've implemented an enum with a `Unknown` case:

```
enum Result: Int {
  case Success
  case Failure
  case Foo
  case Bar
  case FooBar
  case FooFoo
  ...
  case Unknown = -1
}
```

I want to create another initializer that takes an `Int` and returns `Unknown` for case not recognized by the enum:

```
init(value: Int) {
  self.init(rawValue: value)
  if self == nil { // Complication Error
    self = .Unknown
  }
}
```

My solution for now is a Factory method, however an initializer would be much cleaner:

```
static func resultWithValue(value: Int) -> Result {
  if let result = self(rawValue: value) {
    return result
  }
  return .Unknown
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While you can’t delegate to a failable initializer, since enums are value types, you can just try creating another value of the same enum using the failable initializer, and then substitute a default in case of `nil`, and assign that to `self`:

```
enum Result: Int {
    case Success
    case Failure
    case Unknown = -1

    init(value: Int) {
        self = Result(rawValue: value) ?? .Unknown
    }
}

Result(value: 100) == .Unknown  // returns true
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm embarrassed I didn't think to use the type name in the initializer.

Comment: Hah! I was insisting to make it work by trying with `self.init(....` ..no way. I felt odd when I saw the solution is simply `self = ` etc. :-) thanks.

Comment: If anyone else is trying to create an initializer that delegates to a failable initializer but stops execution when it fails (e.g. preconditionFailure()) the following works:

`init(unsafeValue: Int) { guard let result = Result(rawValue: unsafeValue) else { preconditionFailure("Unsafe value was not a valid result") } self = result }`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781425/use-self-in-convenience-initializers-to-delegate-to-jsondecoder-or-factory-m if you need to do something like this on a class where `self =` is unavailable.

Comment: Although you can't say `self.init`, you can say `self = Self(....` instead of `self = Result(....`, although it's not necessarily clearer code!